# Limit of a Trigonometric Function by Substitution

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How to solve this limit:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi} \frac{1+\cos(7t)}{\sin^{2}(4t)}$$

by using the substitution $\varphi=\pi - t$.

I tried using trigonometric identities but it just gets messier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=\pi-t$ so using the trigonometric properties and the Taylor series we find

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \pi} \frac{1+\cos(7t)}{\sin^{2}(4t)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(7x)}{\sin^{2}(4x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{49x^2}{2}}{16x^2}=\frac{49}{32}$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, but I have not seen Taylor Series or l'Hopital's rule

Comment: Do you know the "famous" relations
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac12$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1\quad ?$$
If yes so use it with changing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well use L'Hospital's rule twice. $$\lim_{t \to \pi} \frac{1 + \cos(7t)}{\sin^2(4t)} = \lim_{t \to \pi} \frac{-7 \sin(7t)}{2 \sin(4t)\cos(4t) 4} = \lim_{t \to \pi}\frac{-7\sin(7t)}{4\sin(8t)}$$
Using L'Hospital again: $$\lim_{t \to \pi}\frac{-7\sin(7t)}{4\sin(8t)} = \lim_{t \to \pi} \frac{-49 \cos(7t)}{32\cos(8t)} = \frac{-49}{32} \frac{-1}{1} = \frac{49}{32}.$$